# How to test Yandex AppMetrica Deferred deeplinks on Android?

Tags: android, yandex

I want to test Deferred deeplink on my Android device before release it in Google Play 
There is no information on [this](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/docs/mobile-sdk-dg/android/about/android-deferred-deeplinks.html?lang=en) page how to test. Also there is no available information in the internet, maybe someone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your existing [cabinet](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/) or create new one
2. Open [Tracking -> Create Tracker](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/campaign), select your Application, choose MediaSource as **Google Search**, add **SmartLink** where AppStore is **Google Play** click save and copy the generated **Tracking URL** 
    As example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircJZ.png) you can find a screenshot!
3. Open **Tracking URL** via your Android phone and it will redirect you at **Google Store**. Do not click anything!
4. Install your app via **adb** command `adb install app.apk`. Make sure that your app have the same **applicationID** as in **Google Play**  id `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=`**applicationID**`&...`
5. Open your app and your will received what you set in the url in your specified listener. Keep in mind that deferred deeplink can be requested during first launch only!

```
YandexMetrica.requestDeferredDeeplink(object : DeferredDeeplinkListener {
    override fun onDeeplinkLoaded(deeplink: String) = Log.d("Deeplink", "deeplink = $deeplink")
    override fun onError(error: DeferredDeeplinkListener.Error, referrer: String?) = Unit
})
```